# using object in whole module. Python

Tags: python, object

When I create an object in some method, I can't use it in any other method. So the use of the object is limited just to that method. But I would like to create the object somehow, that could use it in my whole module.

Here is the code of the module in which I want to create the object so I could use it in every method. (It's not so important what it should do, but for those who cares, it'll be network configurator which using netlink socket to communicate with the kernel).

In the method `configureBridge()` (the 4th method from the beginning) I tried to create an object and use it (`ip = IPRoute()` ... `ip.release()`) and it worked, but I couldn't use the object variable `ip` in any other function apart from `configureBridge()`. Could someone help me with that?

```
class PyrouteTwo(Configurator):
    def __init__(self, inRollback=False):
        super(PyrouteTwo, self).__init__(ConfigApplier(), inRollback)
        self.runningConfig = RunningConfig()
        logging.debug("testmark.PyR2.init")

    def begin(self):
        if self.configApplier is None:
            self.configApplier = ConfigApplier()
        if self.runningConfig is None:
            self.runningConfig = RunningConfig()
        logging.debug("testmark.PyR2.begin")

    def commit(self):
        self.configApplier = None
        self.runningConfig.save()
        self.runningConfig = None
        logging.debug("testmark.PyR2.commit")

    def configureBridge(self, bridge, **opts):
        self.configApplier.addBridge(bridge)
        if bridge.port:
            bridge.port.configure(**opts)
            self.configApplier.addBridgePort(bridge)
        self.configApplier.setIfaceConfigAndUp(bridge)
        logging.debug("testmark.PyR2.confBridge..")

        # I am using the object here:
        ip = IPRoute(fork=True)
        dev = ip.link_lookup(ifname='em1')[0]
        logging.debug("pyroute2 link_lookup output: %d", dev)
        ip.release()


# there are some similar functions like configureVAN etc. in which I want 
# to use the object

class ConfigApplier(object):
    def _setIpConfig(self, iface):
        ipConfig = iface.ipConfig
        logging.debug("testmark.PyR2.ConfApplier.setIpConf.")
        if ipConfig.ipaddr:
            self.removeIpConfig(iface)
            ipwrapper.addrAdd(iface.name, ipConfig.ipaddr,
                              ipConfig.netmask)
            if ipConfig.gateway and ipConfig.defaultRoute:
                ipwrapper.routeAdd(['default', 'via', ipConfig.gateway])

    def removeIpConfig(self, iface):
        ipwrapper.addrFlush(iface.name)

    def setIfaceMtu(self, iface, mtu):
        ipwrapper.linkSet(iface, ['mtu', str(mtu)])

    def ifup(self, iface):
        ipwrapper.linkSet(iface.name, ['up'])
        if iface.ipConfig.bootproto == 'dhcp':
            dhclient = DhcpClient(iface.name)
            dhclient.start(iface.ipConfig.async)

    def ifdown(self, iface):
        ipwrapper.linkSet(iface.name, ['down'])
        dhclient = DhcpClient(iface.name)
        dhclient.shutdown()

    def setIfaceConfigAndUp(self, iface):
        if iface.ip:
            self._setIpConfig(iface)
        if iface.mtu:
            self.setIfaceMtu(iface.name, iface.mtu)
        self.ifup(iface)

    def addBridge(self, bridge):
        rc, _, err = execCmd([EXT_BRCTL, 'addbr', bridge.name])
        if rc != 0:
            raise ConfigNetworkError(ERR_FAILED_IFUP, err)

    def addBridgePort(self, bridge):
        rc, _, err = execCmd([EXT_BRCTL, 'addif', bridge.name,
                              bridge.port.name])
        if rc != 0:
            raise ConfigNetworkError(ERR_FAILED_IFUP, err)

    def removeBridge(self, bridge):
        rc, _, err = execCmd([EXT_BRCTL, 'delbr', bridge.name])
        if rc != 0:
            raise ConfigNetworkError(ERR_FAILED_IFDOWN, err)
        logging.debug("testmarkPyR2.ConfApplier.remBridge")

    # ... 

    def createLibvirtNetwork(self, network, bridged, iface, qosInbound=None,
                             qosOutbound=None):
        netXml = libvirtCfg.createNetworkDef(network, bridged, iface,
                                             qosInbound, qosOutbound)
        libvirtCfg.createNetwork(netXml)
        logging.debug("testmarkPyR2.ConfApplier.createLibvirtNetwork")

    def removeLibvirtNetwork(self, network):
        libvirtCfg.removeNetwork(network)
        logging.debug("testmarkPyR2.ConfApplier.remLibvirtNetwork")
```

Comment: Initialize all your variables in `__init__` even if it is currently `None`, then you can assign them values whenever you need to.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters thanks for the corrections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either declare it as object specific attibute by doing -

```
self.ip = value   # Now its a object specific variable
```

or make it a class veriable before assign it a value.

```
class PyrouteTwo(Configurator):
    ip = None    # Now its a class variable
```